# applying template using variable in XSLT

Tags: javascript, xslt-2.0

what is the best way to apply a template according to a variable in xslt? the variable will change through a java script code. i have read about the function in xslt v 2.0 but the answer was not explained very well and it didn't match my requires.

i've tried the next:

i've created a global variable

```
<xsl:variable name="module" select='"C"' />
```

then applied it like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='module[@name="$module"]/categorys' />
```

then matched it like this

```
<xsl:template match='module[@name="C"]/categorys'>
```

but nothing displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable of type string and you want to compare it then reference it with `$varname` but don't put it inside of string literal delimiters.

So use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="module[@name = $module]/categorys"/>
```

to apply templates to the `categorys` child elements of those `module` elements where the `name` attribute has the value `C`.